# Disable Scroll under bootstrap modal overlay

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popup, modal-dialog, overlay, touchmove

I have scrollable content under the bootstrap modal. When i touchmove on the popup overlay, I can still scroll the content under the modal. Can it be disabled somehow?

Tested on iPad mini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a known issue](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-fixed-position-keyboards) caused by bugs/deficiencies in the mobile browsers themselves. No acceptable fix is currently known. From the Bootstrap docs:

> ### Overflow and scrolling
>
> Support for `overflow: hidden` on the `<body>` element is quite limited in iOS and Android. To that end, when you scroll past the top or bottom of a modal in either of those devices' browsers, the `<body>` content will begin to scroll.